# 3 Monitors on GTX 460 and P7H55-PRO

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card, integrated-graphics

I have a dual monitor setup on my GTX 460. I'd like to use the integrated graphics combo of my P7H55-PRO + I3 550 to display a 3rd monitor. This won't be used for gaming, just for more work space. Is it possible? The integrated display adapter won't show up in the device manager at all. The monitor is plugged in and powered, and working, but doesn't show up in display settings.

```
OS = Windows 7 64bit
RAM = 8GB
```

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if there's any option to turn on the on-board video card in your BIOS. The problem is, most on-board video is disabled when you have a discrete graphics card installed into the system.

Comment: I did look in the Bios for that option, but there was nothing. There is a new Bios available from what I'm using. I plan on updating the Bios to see if that option was later made available. I'm also thinking of just biting the bullet and pulling the trigger on a GTX 660. 

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 supports multiple graphics cards, even if they are from different vendors. So yes, this can work.

There are three catches though:

1. You need to enable both sets of graphics cards. For the dedicated card this simply means plugging it in, connecting cables etc. Some older motherboards with integrated cards turn theirs off by default if you plug in a dedicated card. This means going into the BIOS and changing the integrated graphics from 'auto' to 'enabled'.
2. Some broken motherboards always disable integrated graphics if a PCI-e card is detected. Even if it is not a graphics card. Never buy from them again.
3. If both cards use the same drivers but different versions then you are out of luck. E.g. an ancient nvidia card only supported in legacy drivers and a modern one (with no support in legacy).